# What does it mean to 'wrap' a function?

Tags: javascript

I've been running across this idea and struggle to understand its meaning.

This is one example:

'In terms of what they can express, callbacks and promises are equivalent. Callback-based functions can be wrapped to expose a promise-based interface, and vice versa.'

I'm less interested in the context of this example, than I am in what it means to 'wrap a function'.

Comment: "what it means to 'wrap a function'." - Nothing fancy. A wrapper is just a function that calls another function and possibly transforms its input or output or something else.

Comment: The word means the same as it does in standard English. You put a promise around the call to the function that takes a calback.

Comment: `parseInt` is a function. `parseHex = x => parseInt(x, 16)` is a function that wraps `parseInt`